# How to get the current class' name in a static method?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, static

Normally I can call this.GetType(), but I can't access this in a static method. How can we check it?

Comment: Look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/552629/c-sharp-print-the-class-name-from-within-a-static-function

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
new StackFrame().GetMethod().DeclaringType
```

or

```
MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType
```

or

```
new StackTrace(true).GetFrame(<frame index>).GetMethod() //e.g. <frame index> = 0
```

Answer (score 13):

Use *typeof*:

```
string className = typeof(MyClass).Name;
```

Comment: this one will not work if the code is pasted to another class

Comment: @lo Yes but renaming class keeps the correct typeof statement.

Comment: @lo If you copy class by ReSharper's *Copy Type* refactoring the typeof statement should remain correct too.

Comment: By this same token, you can now simply do `nameof(MyClass)`, as of C# 6.0.